# How to Override Drupal Views Query?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

How can I replace a Views 3 query with a custom SQL query in code?

Comment: Views 3 is still in alpha.  Are you sure that Views 2 cannot do what you want?

Comment: Yes, Views 3 is a requirement. Views 3 seems to be relatively mature at this point in my experience.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I mean - if you're going to completely override the query, then why use Views at all?

Comment: One example would be if a component was originally built as a view and themed in that form and then later on requirements change so as the query that is needed would be too complicated for Views to create. It would be great to replace just the query of the view thereby ensuring that the styling of the output is not affected.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you can use [hook_views_query_alter](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_query_alter/7) to modify the query. I would assume you could also use it to replace the query. Here are a couple hook_views_query_alter examples, to get you started:

- [Using Hook Views Query Alter](http://www.appnovation.com/using-hook-views-query-alter)
- [Alter a View query to add a WHERE clause with OR group operator](http://openspring.net/tip/alter-a-view-query-to-add-a-where-clause-with-or-group-operator).

Answer (score 1):

This might no longer be pertinent to you, but there's what seems to be a very useful discussion on Drupal.org at [Implementing custom SQL query for Views / Filters](http://drupal.org/node/409808) that looks like it's answering my similar question.

In particular, the initial poster has suggested attaching to hook `views_views_pre_execute`, which someone else mentioned can be put into a custom module like:

```
function mymodulename_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
   if($view->name=="groups_list2") {
      // ...
      $view->build_info['query'] = "SELECT node.nid AS nid ".
         "FROM node WHERE node.type='%s'"; // wrapped for legibility
   }
}
```

And another poster mentioned [mySQL Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) and [Table Wizard](http://drupal.org/project/tw) ([direct link](http://drupal.org/node/409808#comment-2560626)), though they did mention it's worth bearing in mind [this article about mySQL Views performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/)

It's definitely worth reading the whole thread on Drupal.org, though, as I found it really useful; I hope someone else does too.

**Update:** Indeed, this is precisely what we're now doing — overriding `views_views_pre_execute` in a custom module to inject new SQL before it gets to the database. I had opened a similar (but more specific) question on Drupal.SE at [Slow query with large dataset in Drupal views — better to process in SQL or PHP?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/26874/3966), which you might find useful.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to execute custom SQL (that Views cannot generate), for example computed fields, or complicated SQL joins, then what you are after is a custom module.

See [drupal](http://drupal.org/node/231276) for a guide to get you started

Comment: Understood. I was looking more for what views hook I can use to override the SQL query.